# unable t0 change Colour of excel cells dynamically in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

Iam using TIBCO jasper studio for generating excel report. I am not able to change the back color of a cell based on a condition. I can change the fontcolor  by setting fontcolor="yellow" But backcolor="yellow" doesnt work. Can anyone help me?

```
<style name="highlight1">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{assoDet1}.equalsIgnoreCase( "1")]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="yellow"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
```

Following is my entire jrxml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.2.final using     JasperReports Library version 6.2.2  -->
     <!-- 2018-04-13T11:09:17 -->
      <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="DetectorStatusReport" pageWidth="992" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="952" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ced95029-b569-4027-895c-af2843a4e088">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="false" />
<style name="Title"  fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="true"/>
<style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#736343" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18"/>
<style name="Column header"  forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
<style name="Detail" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12"/>

<style name="highlight1">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{assoDet1}.equalsIgnoreCase( "1")]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="yellow"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{assoDet2}.equalsIgnoreCase( "1")]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque"  backcolor="yellow"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{assoDet3}.equalsIgnoreCase( "1")]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque"  backcolor="yellow"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>


    <parameter name="junctionName" class="java.lang.String">
    <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
</parameter>
<parameter name="frm_date" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="to_date" class="java.lang.String"/>




<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>

<field name="d1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[d1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="d2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[d2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>



<field name="assoDet1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[assoDet1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>

<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>

    <title>
    <band height="46" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
        <frame>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-20" y="-20" width="1000" height="50" uuid="b87c1b65-3be3-42ce-885f-21b7d1f29a17">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Title" positionType="Float" x="19" y="10" width="234" height="30" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="bbd2692e-1dc1-49c7-b2a1-632af2ef9f16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="16" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Detector Status Report of]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Title" x="253" y="10" width="170" height="30" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="dcb43670-d7cf-4f90-86a7-c309c36f294a"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="16"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{junctionName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="434" y="4" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="ba7b5931-84f5-450e-aac8-9df1a0284ea0"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[From:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="434" y="25" width="41" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="255a4119-bc96-4b89-ad3f-5bdec46a0d12"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[To:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="474" y="4" width="102" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="fd0e002e-6e43-429e-aca3-a55ed00b3ec3"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{frm_date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="475" y="25" width="101" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="03165034-543c-4a51-bc54-004105ecc771"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{to_date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
</title>


<pageHeader>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="0" y="-3" width="960" height="30" uuid="8c3a60a6-57fa-48a1-9109-985db3a2e591"/>


                <reportElement style="Column header" x="330" y="0" width="20" height="27" forecolor="#736343" uuid="5049e8a5-21bb-4244-8cd5-f2ccb6efd3e1"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[D1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="350" y="0" width="17" height="27" forecolor="#736343" uuid="bdbe019d-99fd-4800-8ac4-a78c4aae68cb"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[D2]]></text>
            </staticText>


        </frame>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement  mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="960" height="30" uuid="a98495d8-3c8d-4fa0-81f5-30c3efc2f766"/>


                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{d1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="highlight1" x="350" y="0" width="17" height="30" uuid="03e139a2-8e8f-465f-b4bb-80ad55da9064">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{d2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>


        </frame>
    </band>
</detail>
```

And another thing is, if i change style to forecolor="yellow" ,It works fine. problem is with backcolor. Also I'm not able to include heading in the report.

Comment: Post the JRXML file contents, not merely the JRTX snippet.

Comment: Your style definition is valid. You should post the small *jrxml* to reproduce the issue